# Problem on gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the points $(x,y)$ and the directions for which the directional derivative of $f (x,y)=3x^2+y^2$ has its largest value if $(x,y)$ is on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$. Can anyone tell me how to solve this??

Comment: It would help if we could see your calculation of the directional derivative.

Comment: Well I tried to find grad of the function and then noting the fact grad f should be zero if the directional derivative is at largest value. Then substituting (x,y) which will satisfy the equation of the circle I calculated my answer

Comment: Is it the right method

Comment: No, you need to find the points where the gradient vector has maximal norm. The directional derivative has its largest value at these points, in the direction of the gradient vector. Can you update your question with the result of $\|\text{grad} f\|^2$ ?

Comment: $36x^2+4y^2$.....

Comment: Exactly $36 x^2+ 4 y^2 = 32 x^2 + 4$ on the circle. This is maximal when $x = \pm 1$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: What is $32x^2+4$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65023/discussion-between-gribouillis-and-user426700).

Comment: Ok then how do u find$x=\pm 1$. Sorry can't write anything in chat window

Comment: $32 x^2 + 4$ is maximum when $x^2$ is maximum. On the circle, this happens when $x = \pm 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = (m,n)$ with $m^2+n^2 =1 $ be the unit vector and let $D_u f$ be the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $u$. Then we have: $(D_u f)^2= (f_xm+f_yn)^2 = (6xm+2yn)^2\le (36x^2+4y^2)(m^2+n^2)= 36x^2+4y^2 = 32x^2+4(x^2+y^2) = 32x^2+4\le 32+4 = 36$ with equality attains at $x = \pm 1, y = 0, m = \pm 1, n = 0$. Thus the max of $D_uf$ is $6$.

Comment: I can't understand what u did?? Can u explain if u don't mind

Comment: $D_u f = (f_x,f_y)\cdot (u_1,u_2) = (6x,2y)\cdot (m,n) = .....$,and the next step is using the CS inequality and the constraint $||u || = 1 = m^2+n^2$, the third step makes use of the given $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and also $x^2 \le 1$. Rest is easy !